# How to convert a graphNEL object to a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to convert a graphNEL object into a data frame, is there a way to do this?

I tried

```
dataframe <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(graphnel))
```

but I got the error message that it is not a graph object (graphnel is the name of my variable holding the graphNEL object)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. It kind of looks like you are mixing objects and functions from the **graph** and **igraph** packages, but it's hard to tell without some reproducible code.

Comment: this is my code: https://github.com/materechm/Bioinformatics/blob/master/pathways.R

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert graphnel to igraph first.
dataframe <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(igraph.from.graphNEL(graphnel)))

Good luck.